# HTML <A href> link to another html doesn't work

Tags: html, css, href

I'm trying to link to another html in the same folder, but it doesn't work. The bottom ones with id="diaweiter" and id="diazurueck" work, but the upper ones don't and I can't figure out why.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#startanimation {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#dia {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1039px;
  height: 621px;
  margin-top: 459px;
  margin-left: 881px;
}


/* Menue */

#bgweiter {
  position: fixed;
  width: 125px;
  height: 215px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 12, 12);
  margin-left: 1800px;
  z-index: 20;
}

#bgzurueck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 125px;
  height: 215px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 12, 12);
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#diaweiter {
  position: fixed;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 12, 12);
  margin-top: 705px;
  margin-left: 1800px;
  z-index: 20;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#diazurueck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 12, 12);
  margin-top: 705px;
  margin-left: 875px;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* uebergreifend */

a:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

a.start {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="dynwald3_1.html">
  <div id="bgweiter"> </div>
</a>

<a href="dynwald1_1.html">
  <div id="bgzurueck"> </div>
</a>

<div id="content">
  <div id="bg1">
    <image src="bg/NPZ Dynamik Wald Layout2.png" width="1920px" height="1080px" />
  </div>
</div>


<div id="dia">
  <div id="bg1">
    <image src="dias/02/Wald10.png" width="1039px" height="621px" />
  </div>
</div>

<a href="dynwald2_2.html">
  <div id="diaweiter"> </div>
</a>

<a href="dynwald2_3.html">
  <div id="diazurueck"> </div>
</a>
```

It's really frustrating that the lower ones in the code work, while the upper don't and I'm completely lost on what to do.

I googled and tried different ways to link but nothing helps.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that you've set `position: fixed` on the elements inside the links, so the links are basically empty. Either style the links or wrap them with whatever you're positioning fixed.

Comment: "*doesn’t work*" is usually not a particularly helpful problem statement, can you describe a bit more in detail what you did, what you *expected* to happen, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might just be a positioning issue: As you are using `position: fixed` with large margins, some elements might actually be rendering outside the viewport.

You can see how pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can get all of them to focus (and you'll see the link show up in the bottom-left corner of your browser):

[image]

Placing them differently makes all of them visible and clickable regardless of scroll position (assuming that's what you want):

```css
body {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#bgweiter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  background: red;
}

#bgzurueck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: green;
}

#diaweiter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  background: blue;
}

#diazurueck {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="dynwald3_1.html">
  <div id="bgweiter"> </div>
</a>

<a href="dynwald1_1.html">
  <div id="bgzurueck"> </div>
</a>

<a href="dynwald2_2.html">
  <div id="diaweiter"> </div>
</a>

<a href="dynwald2_3.html">
  <div id="diazurueck"> </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you so much! Such a simple thing and I didn't realize...